# TLS 1.3 C# Client Implementation - Decryption Failure

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, public-key-encryption, tls1.3

I am implementing my own TLS 1.3 client in c#.
Currently I am struggle with Handshake messages decryption.
When I look at packages in Wireshark the "Application Data" after ServerHello is 4569 Bytes long. Seems like it is waaaay too much.

[image]

The decryption with .log file is not working for that connection. If I take any other connection for sample page, decryption works fine and I see whole handshake - it is approx. 500bytes long. Not 4,5k bytes

[image]

I went through [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#page-93) more than 3 times now and seems to me that 4,5k is not a good length. Am I missing something?

The algorithm for decoding handshake look like this:

```
// (1) Check HelloHash, Client and Server Hello are without header
var combinedHelloMessages = new List<byte>();
combinedHelloMessages.AddRange(ClientHelloMsg);
combinedHelloMessages.AddRange(ServerHelloMsg);

var hashEngine = SHA256.Create();
var computedHash = hashEngine.ComputeHash(combinedHelloMessages.ToArray()).ToList();


// (2) Calculate Shared Secred Key
// Based on our client PrivateKey and server PublicKey
var SSK = new byte[32];
var serverPublicKeyParam = new X25519PublicKeyParameters(serverPublicKey);

var x25519PrivateParam = new X25519PrivateKeyParameters(clientPrivateKey);
x25519PrivateParam.GenerateSecret(serverPublicKeyParam, SSK, 0);
```

The Handshake key calculations:

```
public static (byte[] clientHandshakeKey, byte[] clientHandshakeIV, byte[] serverHandshakeKey, byte[] serverHandshakeIV) HandshakeKeysCalculations
        (byte[] helloHash, byte[] clientSSK)
    {
        byte[] zeroKey = new byte[32] {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0
        };

        byte[] inputKeyingMaterial = new byte[32] {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0
        };

        var empty_STRING = new byte[0];

        var transcriptHash = SHA256.Create();

        byte[] earl_secret = HKDF.Extract(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, inputKeyingMaterial, zeroKey);
        byte[] derived_secret = DeriveSecret(earl_secret, "derived", empty_STRING, 32, transcriptHash);
        byte[] handshakeSecret = HKDF.Extract(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, clientSSK, derived_secret);

        byte[] client_handshake_secret = DeriveSecret(handshakeSecret, "c hs traffic", helloHash, 32, transcriptHash);
        byte[] server_handshake_secret = DeriveSecret(handshakeSecret, "s hs traffic", helloHash, 32, transcriptHash);

        byte[] clientHandshakeKey = ExpandLabel(client_handshake_secret, "key", empty_STRING, 32);
        byte[] clientHandshakeIV = ExpandLabel(client_handshake_secret, "iv", empty_STRING, 12);

        byte[] serverHandshakeKey = ExpandLabel(server_handshake_secret, "key", empty_STRING, 32);
        byte[] serverHandshakeIV = ExpandLabel(server_handshake_secret, "iv", empty_STRING, 12);

        return (clientHandshakeKey, clientHandshakeIV, serverHandshakeKey, serverHandshakeIV);
    }
 private static byte[] DeriveNonce(byte[] iv, ulong seq)
    {
        var nonce = new byte[iv.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, nonce, 0, iv.Length);
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            nonce[nonce.Length - 1 - i] = (byte)(iv[iv.Length - 1 - i] ^ (byte)((seq >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF));
        return nonce;
    }

    public static byte[] DeriveSecret(byte[] secret, string label, byte[] messages, int lenght, HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
    {
        // I Compute the hash once
        //var transcript = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(messages);
        return ExpandLabel(secret, label, messages, (ushort)lenght);
    }

    public static byte[] ExpandLabel(byte[] secret, string label, byte[] context, ushort len)
    {
        var hkdfLabel = HkdfLabel(label, context, len);
        return HKDF.Expand(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, secret, len, hkdfLabel);
    }

    static byte[] HkdfLabel(string label, byte[] context, ushort len)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var lenBytes = UInt16Bytes(len);
            var labelBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tls13 " + label);

            ms.Write(lenBytes, 0, lenBytes.Length);
            ms.WriteByte((byte)labelBytes.Length);
            ms.Write(labelBytes, 0, labelBytes.Length);
            ms.WriteByte((byte)context.Length);
            ms.Write(context, 0, context.Length);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] UInt16Bytes(ushort u16)
    {
        return new[] { (byte)((u16 & 0xFF00) >> 8), (byte)(u16 & 0x00FF) };
    }
```

And final Decryption

```
// https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-5.3
var nonce = DeriveNonce(serverHandshakeIV, recordNumber);

var cipher = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Modes.ChaCha20Poly1305();
byte[] decrypted = new byte[ApplicationDataRecord.Length];

KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(serverHandshakeKey);
ParametersWithIV keyParamWithIV = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, nonce);

cipher.Init(false, keyParamWithIV);

var len = cipher.ProcessBytes(ApplicationDataRecord, 0, ApplicationDataRecord.Length, decrypted, 0);

try
{
    cipher.DoFinal(decrypted, len);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

I am helping myself with

- [RFC 8439](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8439)
- [RFC 8446](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446)
- [The Illustrated TLS 1.3 Connection](https://tls13.xargs.org)
- [TLSHandler](https://github.com/whSwitching/TLSHandler/tree/master)

Comment: TLS is performed before the HTTP request is send.  TLS the server sends the names (one or more) of certificates which may be why the length is longer.  When TLS fails you never see the HTTP Request.  In second picture you are seeing the HTTP Request and you are getting a 200 OK which indicates TLS is working.  The first TLS is failing.  TLS the server send a certificate block with names (one of more) of certificates.  The client than look up the names in stores to find matching certificate.

Comment: With Net 4.7.1 or later TLS is automatically performed by the OS, not inside Net.  Did you turn off the OS sending TLS?  Look at the ACKs.  The HELLO should be returned which is occurring in second picture.  The first picture there is no ack immediately after the hello.  It looks like more than one connection is being established between client and server, or the sniffer is showing retries from a previous failed attempt.

Comment: "I am implementing my own TLS 1.3 client in c#" why reinvent the wheel? Just use `HttpClient` or a combination of `TcpClient` and `SslStream`, which can do all this much better.

Comment: @jdweng - I am using windows so turning of the TLS 1.2/TLS 1.3 might help? Will it make browsers and other stuff not working?
And also many certificaces... hmm how can It be that via Chorme i.e. the communication looks the same? And it works there, I got simple json from server in the browser. I looked at other tls1.3 connections and it seems that it is max 1,5k Bytes

Comment: @jdweng - I know that tls1.3 is failing because I am closing the connection from my client. I cannot decrypt handshake after ServerHello.

Comment: You need to make sure the ACK is immediately after the hello.  You may be going through a proxy which is why there are extra messages.  Read following to disable OS and use Net for TLS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#for-http-networking

Comment: Why is 4500+ bytes way too much for the *application data*? That is not part of the handshake, the handshake has already completed.

Comment: I was a network engineer for 5 years debugging TCP issues.  Make sure you are not getting retries.  Always check the sequence numbers, ack, and time between message.  Also make sure you do not have more than one machine with the same IP address.  All this can cause wrong interpretation of the sniffer data.  Always look for the first wrong response in the sniffer data.  Anything after the first wrong response can easily lead to wrong conclusion.